# In C I can assign void* to char* but not in C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, char, void-pointers

If the file is .c MSVC will compile.

If it's .cpp it `"cannot convert from 'void *' to 'unsigned char *'"`

I'm using the `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION::BaseAddress` in `windows.h` which is `void*`, assigning it to a `char*` so I can see the actual address you know?

When I cast it to char*, and later back to `void*` (to use it in windows functions), it like bugs out and loses data or something

What to do?

Comment: Are you trying to print out a memory address by converting it to a char pointer?

Comment: can you put a simple code not working ?

Comment: No, we don't know.  Why do you need to cast it to `char*` to see the address?  `printf("%p")` works on `void*`.

Comment: What does "it like bugs out and loses data or something" mean?

Comment: yes I guess I cant convert it back to void* after the char*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++, you must use an explicit cast to convert a `void*` to anything else:

```
void *vp;
unsigned char *cp = static_cast<unsigned char *>(vp);
```

This is indeed different from the situation in C, where a `void*` can be implicitly converted to any other pointer type. The reverse situation is still as in C:

```
void *vp = cp;  // no need for a static_cast
```

However, I don't see why you'd need a `char*` to "see the actual address" as a `void*` can be printed as-is by `operator<<` on `std::ostream` and by `std::printf` with `%p`.